# Reason why int(*g)(int) into int(*h)(char) causes error?

Tags: c++, c

I am studying programming language principles and I have a question with C and C++.

```
int (*f)(int);
int (*g)(int);
int (*h)(char);

f = g; // ok
h = g; // warning in C, error in C++
```

Assigning `g` into `f` (`f = g`) will not cause an error in C or C++, but assigning `g` into `h` (`h = g`) would generate a compiler warning in C and compile error in C++.

I heard that the `char` type is usually auto-casted into `int` in C++, so I thought this would not cause an error.

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Note: There is no such language as C/C++. They are different, distinct, languages.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Question is about a difference between these two.

Comment: Yes, a `char` object can be implicitly converted (auto-casted) to an `int` object. But this does not imply that a pointer to the function that has a parameter of type `char` can be implicitly converted to the pointer to the function that has a parameter of type `int`. Even a simple pointer to `char` cannot be implicitly converted into a pointer to `int`.

Comment: So the reason would be that these are about function pointers, not about char or int type. Thank you so much for the comments.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Yes, I understand that. I was getting at the statements like "I got a question with C/C++.", implying that they are a singular thing. Which is not true.

Answer (score 3):

For two function types to be compatible, the returns types must match and the number and types of the arguments must match.  The conversion rules that apply between integer types do not apply to arguments of function types.

Section 6.7.6.3p15 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) states the following:

> **For two  function  types  to  be  compatible,  both  shall  specify  compatible  return  types. Moreover,  the  parameter  type  lists,  if  both  are  present,  shall  agree  in  the  number  of parameters  and  in  use  of  the  ellipsis  terminator;  corresponding  parameters  shall  have compatible types.**  If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function  declarator  that  is  not  part  of  a  function  definition  and  that  contains  an  empty identifier list, the parameter list shall not have an ellipsis terminator and the type of each parameter  shall  be  compatible  with  the  type  that  results  from  the  application  of  the default argument promotions.  If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function definition that contains a (possibly empty) identifier list, both shall agree  in  the  number  of  parameters,  and  the  type  of  each  prototype  parameter  shall  be compatible  with  the  type  that  results  from  the  application  of  the  default  argument promotions  to  the  type  of  the  corresponding  identifier.   (In  the  determination  of  type compatibility  and  of  a  composite  type,  each  parameter  declared  with  function  or  array type is taken as having the adjusted type and each parameter declared with qualified type is taken as having the unqualified version of its declared type.)

The types `int` and `char` are not compatible with each other, therefore a function with one `int` parameter and another with one `char` parameter are not compatible with each other, making the assignment in your example invalid.

C compilers will typically warn when attempting a conversion between incompatible pointer types.  Attempting to defererence `h` in your example by calling the function will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: why is it only a warning ? Is it UB?

Comment: @idclev463035818 yes, it's UB.  Updated.

Answer (score 3):

> Assigning `g` into `f` (`f = g`) will not cause an error in C/C++, but assigning `g` into `h` (`h = g`) would generate a compiler warning in C and compile error in C++.

This is incorrect. A program that attempts to do `h = g` is an invalid program, be it C or C++. However the C standard explicitly mentions that a C compiler is allowed to successfully compile an  invalid program, provided that it issues a *diagnostic message* for every violation of certain rules. You got your warning and then the C compiler proceeded anyhow.

In fact, C++ standard contains a very similar wording:

> If a program contains a violation of any diagnosable rule or an occurrence of a construct described in this document as “conditionally-supported” when the implementation does not support that construct, a conforming implementation shall issue at least one diagnostic message.
>
> [...]
>
> A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do not alter the behavior of any well-formed program. Implementations are required to diagnose programs that use such extensions that are ill-formed according to this document.
> Having done so, however, they can compile and execute such programs.

But customarily C++ compilers are by default *more strict* when it comes to diagnosable violations and the compilation will *fail* by default whereas the C compiler from the same vendor would *successfully* compile such a translation unit.

---

Note that both C and C++ has a provision that you can do the conversion with a *cast*, i.e. `h = (int (*)(char))g`; but you again must not *call* a function through `h` without casting it back to `int (*)(int)` first!

Answer (score 1):

When you define a pointer to a function, you essentially define a new variable type.

So in your example, `f` and `g` are the same type, because they are defined identically, but `h` is another type, because it is defined differently.

While both C and C++ compilers know how to convert between `char` and `int` types, as those are built in to the language, they don't know how to convert between `g` and `h` types, because you defined those.

The fact that `char` is part of `g` definition does not help here, because the compiler has no right to alter the internals of your definitions.

Consider the kind of bugs this could cause:
If you use a calling convention where all arguments are put on the stack, sending a char to a function that expects int would cause it to get a wrong value, as it will be reading extra bytes from the stack that are not part of the sent value.

Answer (score 1):

You might also wonder why those function pointers are not implicitly-convertible into each other. Consider the following function definition:

```
void f(void(*f)(char))
{
    f('A');
}
```

A compiler now needs to generate a machine code for this function. In my case, it was:

```x86asm
mov rax, rdi
mov edi, 65
jmp rax
```

This machine code would generally not work if, as an argument of `f`, would be passed a pointer to a function that has a parameter of a different type. Here, the argument to `f` is passed through the `edi` register. By coincidence, that would work also for a function that has a parameter of type `int` with my implementation. But this is purely an implementation issue and the standard rules may not be driven by it.

For illustration, if I would pass, as an argument of `f`, a pointer to the function that has a parameter of type `long`, this would stop working, since then the argument would not be passed to `f` through the `rdi` register (as this function would expect).